# Прочитать данные из нескольких файлов и записать результаты в последний файл

Tags: java, файлы, шаблоны-проектирования

Нужно создать рабочую структуру, которая принимает список имен файлов из командной строки. Она открывает каждый файл, за исключением последнего, для чтения, а последний для записи. Эта рабочая структура обрабатывает каждый входящий файл, используя неопределенную политику, а затем пишет результат в последний файл. Наследовать от этой рабочей структуры для создания двух разных приложений: Первое конвертирует все литеры каждого файла в верхний регистр. Второе ищет файлы, в которых содержатся слова из первого файла. Мне пока удалось того, чтобы в первом случае в каждом файле менялся регистр, а во втором случае вывода в консоль имен тех файлов, которые содержат слова из первого. Как мне реализовать запись результатов в последний введённый файл, желательно ещё и добавив метод записи в шаблонный класс?(на всякий случай добавил ссылку на проект)

https://github.com/artyomefimov123/lab_2

Answer (score 0):

По большому счету вы на правильном пути.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConvertLiteralsFileProcessor().start();
    }
}

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public abstract class FileProcessor {
    
    public void start() {
        List<String> fileNames = getFiles();
        if (fileNames.isEmpty()) return;
        String result = processFiles(fileNames);        
        writeFile(fileNames.get(fileNames.size()-1), result);
    }

    protected abstract String processFiles(List<String> fileNames);

    private List<String> getFiles() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter file name(to stop write exit): ");
            String fileName = sc.nextLine();
            if ("exit".equals(fileName.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))) break;
            fileNames.add(fileName);
        }
        return fileNames;
    }

    protected String readFile(String filePath) {
        try (Stream<String> lineStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
            return lineStream.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void writeFile(String filePath, String context) {
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), context.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ConvertLiteralsFileProcessor extends FileProcessor {

    @Override
    public String processFiles(List<String> fileNames) {
        return fileNames.stream()
                .limit(fileNames.size()-1)
                .map(filePath -> readFile(filePath).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
    
}

mport java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class WordFileProcessor extends FileProcessor {

    @Override
    public String processFiles(List<String> fileNames) {
        String firstFileContent = new ConvertLiteralsFileProcessor()
                .processFiles(Collections.singletonList(fileNames.get(0)));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i < fileNames.size() - 1; i++) {
            String fileContent = readFile(fileNames.get(i));
            if (checkContext(firstFileContent, fileContent)) sb.append(fileContent).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private boolean checkContext(String firstFileContent, String fileContent) {
        return true; //stub -> todo
    }

}
```

Единственное, что я не понял, что там нужно искать в файлах. поэтому поиск (как и должно по идее быть) вынесен в отдельный приватный метод private boolean checkContext(String firstFileContent, String fileContent), там уже докручивайте